# TypeORM Oracle Driver, works with query.raw but not with entity

Tags: oracle, typeorm

I am able to setup TypeORM connecting to Oracle Driver. With `connection.manager.query`, I can fetch the result correctly.

But when I start to use entity

```
const users1 = await connection.manager.findOne(USER_INFO, 80193220);
```

return `undefined`

or

```
const users2 = await connection.manager.createQueryBuilder()
                        .select("u")
                        .from(USER_INFO, "u")
                        .where("u.uuid = :uuid", { uuid: 80193220 })
                        .getMany();
```

return `[]` despite this one print exactly query in log

```
ctr_1  | query: SELECT USER_INFO.uuid AS USER_INFO_uuid FROM user_info USER_INFO WHERE (USER_INFO.uuid = :id_0_0) -- PARAMETERS: [80193220]
ctr_1  | createQueryBuilder:  undefined
ctr_1  | query: SELECT u.uuid AS u_uuid FROM user_info u WHERE u.uuid = :uuid -- PARAMETERS: [80193220]
ctr_1  | createQueryBuilder:  []
ctr_1  | query: SELECT u.uuid AS u_uuid FROM user_info u WHERE u.uuid = :uuid -- PARAMETERS: [80193220]
ctr_1  | Raw:  [ { U_UUID: 80193220 } ]
```

Source Code
https://github.com/ipoppo/ctr_app

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this. Turns out TypeORM is picky about names and case when converting raw results to entities.

In your case, try changing `from(USER_INFO, "u")`to `from(USER_INFO, "USER_INFO")`.